# Android JUnit Testing, cannot resolve is(boolean) in assertThat?

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, boolean, local

in build.gradle

```
dependencies {    
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
}
```

Code

```
import com.myapp.LVActivity;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class DeviceUnitTest {
    @Test
    public void check_that_is_correct_device_name_isTrue() {
        assertThat(LVActivity.isCorrectDevice("MySpecialDevice"), is(true));
    }
}
```

In LVActivity:

```
private final static String correctName = "MySpecialDevice";
public static boolean isCorrectDevice(String deviceName) {
    return deviceName.equals(correctName);
}
```

The error is here:

```
is(true)
```

Error:

```
Cannot resolve method is(boolean)
```

I am trying to do a simple local unit test.

I'm following this tutorial http://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html

Comment: You'll need  static import of `Matchers.is` or fully qualify the call to say you want to use the `is` method from the `Matchers` class.

Comment: this question saved my time..thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wouldn't you rather just say:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

assertTrue(LVActivity.isCorrectDevice("MySpecialDevice"));
```

This is a more natural expression for checking a boolean.

But if you need to use the `is` matcher with `assertThat`, you will need this import:

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
```